# Textbox value from JSP is unable to insert into the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jsp

I want insert the textbox value into the database. However, only the first textbox is able to insert into the database. Second textbox value could not be inserted into database. (It inserts a blank column instead).

The image below is the data shown in my database. As you can see, only the first exercise shows the number "5". I want both exercises to be able to view it.

[image: MySQL]

[image: HTML]

**JSP code**

```
<% 
        String[] id         = request.getParameterValues("assignchkbox");
        String userId       = request.getParameter("UserID");
        String arm          = request.getParameter("Arm");
        String armNumber    = request.getParameter("ArmNumber");
        String leg          = request.getParameter("Leg");
        String legNumber    = request.getParameter("LegNumber");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(userId);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(arm);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(armNumber);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(leg);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(legNumber);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");


        int count           =0;
        Connection conn     = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://99/hi?user=00&password=000";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);



                    String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm ,ArmNumber,Leg,LegNumber) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    pstmt.setString (1,userId);
                    pstmt.setString (2,arm);
                    pstmt.setString (3,armNumber);
                    pstmt.setString (4,leg);
                    pstmt.setString (5,legNumber);

                int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();

                if (rec==1)
                    count++;


%>


        <form action="assign.jsp" method="post">
            <label><%=count%> assigned!!</label>
            <td style width="50%">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Return" name="ReturnBtn" /></p>
        </form>


<%
conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{

        }


%>
```

**Arm JSP code**

```
<table border='4' class="f">

        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Arm Exercises</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th colspan='1'>&#9989;</th>
        </tr>

        <%

        String sql1="";
        {
            sql1 = "select * from exercise1";
            PreparedStatement pstmt1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);   
            ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()){

            String id       = rs1.getString("ID");
            String arm      = rs1.getString("Arm");

            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td style = 'width: 3%'>");
            out.println(id);
            out.println("</td>"); 
            out.println("<td style = 'width: 90%'>");
            out.println(arm);
            out.println("</td>"); 

        %>

        <td>
            <input name="ArmNumber" id="ArmNumber" type="text" size="2"/>
        </td>

        <td style="width: 5%" class="k"><input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox"
        value="<%=arm%>" form="multipleAssign" name="Arm" /></td>   



        <%
            out.println("</tr>");
                }   
            conn.close();
                }
        %>

        </form>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your insertion logic and have you entered anything in second text box as in the image u haven't entered anything. So it might insert the blank if your insertion logic correct.

Comment: please update whole information about your question....where are your insert code ..??

Comment: Sorry, i have changed to the insert code

Comment: You are trying to send the data to the same page using a form, but I can't see the data which you're sending. In the form, I can just see the `submit` button. Maybe that's the reason this is happening. You're not sending data through the form, and the `request.getParameter()` gives you a null object, which you're inserting

Comment: Which is check box field ArmNumber or assignchkbox

Comment: @SumeshTG i have deleted "assignchkbox" line, my check box field is arm

Comment: @TusharUdayanTiwari sorry, i don't get what you mean

Comment: Do you want insert multiple records ?

Comment: @SumeshTG yes, i want too

Comment: Then read arm as string array using request.getParameterValues and loop through the string array. Fire the insert query inside the loop.

Comment: I am not very familiar with string array, is it possible for you to guide me from my code? @SumeshTG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String[] id         = request.getParameterValues("assignchkbox");
        String userId       = request.getParameter("UserID");
        String arm[]          = request.getParameterValues("Arm");
        String armNumber    = request.getParameter("ArmNumber");
        String leg          = request.getParameter("Leg");
        String legNumber    = request.getParameter("LegNumber");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(userId);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(arm);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(armNumber);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(leg);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(legNumber);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");


        int count           =0;
        Connection conn     = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://99/hi?user=00&password=000";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
            String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm ,ArmNumber,Leg,LegNumber) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            for(String chk:arm){
                  pstmt.setString (1,userId);
                  pstmt.setString (2,chk);
                  pstmt.setString (3,armNumber);
                  pstmt.setString (4,leg);
                  pstmt.setString (5,legNumber);
                  preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        }catch(SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Try this.

Comment: I have figured out a way for multi assign already, thank you so much :)

Comment: However, my textbox is not working. My textbox inserts an empty data into my data base. @sumesh TG

Comment: I think everything you submitted from jsp is an array. Apply same name for all text boxes and recieve them as array.

Comment: How to put two array in a single JSP file? @sumesh TG

Comment: Paste your jsp for creating arm table .

Comment: I have pasted my jsp for arm table :) @sumesh TG

Comment: ya looks fine @Rachelk Use String[] Arm= request.getParameterValues(); then inside loop acces it using index.

Comment: I don't get it. How about my armNumber? Does it need an array too? @sumesh TG

Comment: In you arm table are you need multiple selection or single selection. I mean through checkboxes.

Comment: For my arm table, i need multiple selection for for the arm exercises. However, my arm table **Id 2** textbox could not insert the number into the database. @sumesh tg

Comment: Then you should access all the data in the form of array and iterate multiple arrays simultaneously.

Comment: But your design pattern is totally wrong. Please try to learn MVC design pattern and solve problems based on that.